# JavaFX how i can set Image to my Student (model) from SQL database?

Tags: sql, javafx

Student Model--

Which code I must write to set photo type in the `Student`?

```
package mh.st.model;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Student {
    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty firstName;
    private StringProperty lastName;
    private StringProperty fatherName;
    private IntegerProperty ID;
    private StringProperty phone;
    private StringProperty birthday; 
    private ObjectProperty<Image>photo;

  public Student()
  {

  }  
    public Student(int id,String firstName,String lastName,String fatherName,int ID,String phone,String birthday,Object photo)
    { 
        this.id=new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.firstName=new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName=new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.fatherName=new SimpleStringProperty(fatherName);
        this.ID=new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
        this.phone=new SimpleStringProperty(phone);
        this.birthday=new SimpleStringProperty(birthday);

    }

    public IntegerProperty getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public StringProperty getFatherName() {
        return fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName =new SimpleStringProperty(fatherName);
    }

    public StringProperty getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public StringProperty getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public IntegerProperty getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public StringProperty getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public StringProperty getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName =new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName =new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }

    public void setID(Integer ID) {
        this.ID =new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone =new SimpleStringProperty(phone);
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday =new SimpleStringProperty(birthday);
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is not clear: "Which code I must write to set photo type" . Define photo. What kind of object is it ? A file ? Why is the question tagged as sql ?

Comment: All of your setters are implemented the wrong way. The setter is not supposed to replace the property object but set it's value. Furthermore by convention the getters return the value inside the property object. Methods returning the method itself should be named `propertyNameProperty()` where `propertyName` is replaced by the name of the property, e.g. `phone` or `fatherName`. Furthermore setting the `photo` property depends on the way the data is stored.`Object` provides no info whatsever so this could be anything from`this.photo=new SimpleObjectProperty<>((Image) photo)`to rendering a svg.

Comment: Please review How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)